# Credit card company won’t take their money

Tags: credit-card, banking, legal, debt-collection

Account was transitioning to closing so I couldn’t pay until it transitioned which took over a week of me calling. Attempted to make a payment but it got declined from my debit card which the credit card company figured it was the amount that was charged for the reason of declining. So I gave the account and routing number to them. They said payment went through everything was good.

Now two weeks later it’s still there. Called them and they say my balance is zero it has been paid, call my bank. Called my bank and they can find two transactions for the amount that were DECLINED because of a zip code error and to fix it with credit card company.

Credit card company keeps saying it’s paid! Even sent a letter saying my account is at zero!

Should I save this money? Do I have a chance of fighting this if it comes back on me?? I’m unsure of what to do here

Answer (score 4):

The CC could easily keep a bad transaction around for a couple weeks. Sometimes a regular charge can be "pending" for a while on their systems before it finally fails. I would wait until 30 days (after the next statement date) and then get a written statement showing a $0 balance.

Personally, I would still keep the money for the payment available for 2-3 months *just to be sure*.

If they do discover the discrepancy, unless there is some sort of statute of limitations for this type of thing, you would still be on the hook.

Answer (score 3):

If the credit card company says the account is paid off and closed, and you have that as a printed statement, don't worry about it. If you don't have it in writing, get it in writing.